# Directory path in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In my winform application i need a path like

```
"D:\NEWD\WIN_NEW\Sales\Report\Report2.rdlc"
```

But i  have only `"Sales\Report\Report2.rdlc"` the thing is dat i can't predict this path `D:\NEWD\WIN_NEW` but when am using

```
Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\Sales\\Report\\Report2.rdlc";
```

the path includes my `bin\debug` directory. How can i get the desired path?

Comment: You need to give more info, there is no way to guess some arbitrary path that could be anything

Comment: It's hard to understand the problem. When you move the program to the directory D:\NEWD\WIN_NEW it will work. If you won't do that why can't you just use "D:\NEWD\WIN_NEW\Sales\Report\Report2.rdlc" as the path?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know that you are always going to be in bin\debug you could just do

```
 var path=System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(@"..\..\Sales\Report\Report2.rdlc");
```

Or you could do some detection

```
var path=@"Sales\Report\Report2.rdlc";
var currentDir=System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
if (currentDir.ToLower().EndsWith(@"\bin\debug") ||
    currentDir.ToLower().EndsWith(@"\bin\release")) {

  path=System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(@"..\..\" + path);
} else {
  path=System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(path);
}
```

Another form of detection would be to do the path strip only if you are debugging in which case DEBUG should be set so you could do...

```
var path=@"Sales\Report\Report2.rdlc";
#if DEBUG

path=@"..\..\"+path;

# end if
path=System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(path);
```

This last version has the advantage that all the extra detection is not compiled into your release code.

Answer (score 8):

While youre debugging, the Path of the current directory (the path where the program is executed) will be in the .\bin\debug\ dir.

When you deploy the tool, you wont have this problem anymore.

It seems, you want to deploy the "Sales" directory with your tool: so maybe you should include this in your solution and select it to be copied to the output-directory (.\bin\debug) with your executable.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm, I think this is more triccky question as it seems: 
Considering that now you have `bin\Debug`, on deploy that path disappears, so saying GetCurrentDirectory(), I would say its better to use `Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath)`, you will be retrieved your deploy path. And also one day you may need to change file structure of your deploy, so...

**Just in your bin\Debug or bin\Release replicate your future deploy files/folders layout, so your app will work in DEBUG and in DEPLOY in a same way. Always if it's possible.**

Hope this helps.