# How to get full path to file that "knows" when working in debugger

Tags: c#, file-io

I have an XML file I'm streaming as an XDocument. I need to be able to get the full path of the file (NOT the bin/Debug path) using reflection or the like (so this will be the path from the User's machine it lives on).

I have tried about a zillion different ways, including:

```
 System.Reflection.Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().Location
 System.Reflectin.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location
 System.Reflection.GetExecutingAssembly().Location
 AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.
```

How do I look use System.IO to find the path on the User's machine to my file?? Quite suprised I haven't found the simple answer after googling all day.

::EDIT:: I've now found out that there is no way to "reflectively" locate a path dynamically based on whether the application is running in the debugger or not. My only option is to do some detection.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: where is the xml file located?

Comment: Its a child of my Model folder in my C# application. I just don't want to have to hard-code the path. (That I can do :) )

Comment: I need the directory path that is relevant when the assembly is not executing** if that helps clarify

Comment: Do you want the full path of a directory relative to your current working directory? Or relative to the location of your assembly? Or something else?

Comment: I think the safest way to get the current folder is "Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly.Location)". You will need to add the sub-folder where the xml file resides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found my answer [here (using path stripping and GetFullPath() )](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7174253/1751090). It's a real bummer there's no way around just stripping the bin/debug part of the path. I used the third part of the question linked above.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that the file is in a child directory of the executable?

You can get the full path of the current working directory (ie where your .exe was run from) by using the Environment class. You can then concatanate this with the child directory

```
Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\folder\file.xml"
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.aspx

Hope this helps!

EDIT: After reading up a little it turns out that CurrentDirectory can be changed rather easily. The accepted answer here [Environment.CurrentDirectory is yielding unexpected results when running installed app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343406/environment-currentdirectory-is-yielding-unexpected-results-when-running-install) offers a more reliable method.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisFisher--this ended up being part of the linked question I ended up going with. :)